# Fixing my FFT Plot

Tags: fft, window-functions, java

I'm trying to plot my FFT of File. This i my result.
I made my FFT application:

***I want to obtain something very similar to plot of WaveSpectra, please tell me my mistakes..***

**My FFT**
[image: My FFT]

**The result from WaveSpectra**
[image: The wave Spectra version]
**Other result from WaveSpectra**
[image: Other with WaveSpectra]

Here my code:

```
double[] Samples = null;
try {

  RandomAccessFile rafr = new RandomAccessFile(TheFile, "r");  //TheFile String with path and WAV filename
  //double[] getSamplesFile(rafr,"left",0,8192)  //returns the first 8192 samples of left channel
  Samples = getSamplesFile(rafr,Channel,iPosition,iSizeFFT);
  rafr.close();
}
catch (IOException e) { System.out.println(e.toString()); }
```

**Applying Window Function**

Now I'm trying to apply Window function to Samples, check the code below

```
//double[] getWindow(8192,"hamming"); //was verified against matlab
Samples = applyFilter(Samples,getWindow(iSizeFFT,sWindow));
```

**Trying to Normalize**

Get the Log10 of of absolute value of each complex item of array of FFT, later multiply by 20

```
//fft:  Returns a complex array with FFT (the result was tested and it is equal to Matlab)
//getArrayComplexMod: Returns a double array with absolute value of each complex number
//getRealArrayLog10: Returns a double array with Math.log of each double element
//getRealArrayScalarMult: Returns a double array multiplying each double element with 20.0

Samples = getRealArrayScalarMult(getRealArrayLog10(getArrayComplexMod(fft(Samples))),20.0);
```

**Obtain the Frequency in Hertz**

```
//Now the freq or bins
double[] bins = new double[iSizeFFT];  //Size 8192
Integer SmplRt = 8000; 
for (int i = 0; i < iSizeFFT; i++) {
  bins[i] = (double)i*SmplRt/iSizeFFT;
}
```

**The code to apply filter (or Hamming window) to Samples.**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response#Definition

```
  static double[] applyFilter(double[] dSamples, double[] dFilter) {
    return applyFilter(dSamples, dFilter, 0);
  }

  static double[] applyFilter(double[] dSamples, double[] dFilter, int PosSample) {
    double[] filteredSamples = new double[dSamples.length - PosSample];
    for (int i = PosSample; i < dSamples.length; i++) {
      filteredSamples[i - PosSample] = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < dFilter.length; j++) {
        if(!((i - j) < 0)) {
          filteredSamples[i - PosSample] += dSamples[i-j]*dFilter[j];
        }
      }
    }
    return filteredSamples;
  }
```

**EDIT 1:**
Following the answer of @hotpow2, solved!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be convolving the data with your window instead of just multiplying the data by your window.  e.g.

```
windowedSamples[i] = window[i] * data[i]
```

without any nested convolution loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally a programming question that fits to Stack Overflow, but you missing one part. Frequency scale in case of Wave Spectra is logarithmic, on your plot it is linear. Usually functions like `semilogx` are doing job. Then it's simply setting the x-axis ticks.

Comment: maybe Stackoverflow, My question is represented in Java Code, but the algorithm belong to DSP technics...
I want to know the formula or procedure to deal with FFT to represent it in X logarithmic mode... no matter if not java...